# reciving memory location instead of string output

Tags: java

When I run my program instead of receiving the string from the toString method in my RightTriangle class that I should get normally I instead receive the memory location of the string when I print the object from my driver. How do I fix this problem?

this is the RightTriangleDriver class

```
import java.util.*;
public class RightTriangleDriver
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
        {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner ( System.in );

        System.out.println ( "Enter the length of the first leg " );
        double leg1 = reader.nextDouble ();

        System.out.println ( "Enter the length of the second leg " );
        double leg2 = reader.nextDouble ();

        RightTriangle f1 = new RightTriangle ( leg1, leg2 );
        System.out.println ( f1 );
        }
}
```

this is the RightTriangle class.

```
public class RightTriangle
{
private double leg1;
private double leg2;
private double hyp;

public RightTriangle (double one , double two)
    {
    leg1 = one;
    leg2 = two;
    hyp = Math.sqrt ( Math.pow ( leg1 , 2 ) + Math.pow (leg2 , 2 ) );   
    }

public double perimiter ()
    {
    double perimiter = 0;
    perimiter = leg1 + leg2 + hyp;
    return perimiter;
    }

public double area ()
    {
    double area = 0;
    area = ( leg1*leg2 )/2;
    return area;
    }

public String toSting ()
    {
     String str;
     str = "Leg 1 is " + leg1 + " units long. Leg 2 is " + leg2 + " units long." + "\n" + "the  Hypotenuse is " + hyp +
             " units long." + "\n" + " The perimiter is " + perimiter () + " units and the area is " + area () +
             " units squared.";
     return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is misspelling `toSting` -> `toString`

Comment: fyi, it's not the memory location you are seeing, that's a hash. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

The method name is toString. You have not written correctly.

Whenever you override method of super class use @Override annotation (toString is method of Object class which every class inherit by default). This will help you to know if you are really overriding the method.